# when healthy check in ecs fargate, I got an error, "open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/health" failed (2: No such file or directory)"

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy containers of nginx and fastapi on ECS Fargate. Currently, the issue I am facing is that nginx seems to be unable to pass the health check.

In the load balancer (ALB), I have set up listeners to receive traffic on ports 80 and 443. Port 80 is configured to redirect to port 443. The target group is set to port 80, and the health check is specified to receive a 200 response on the `/health` path. In the ECS service, I've connected the load balancer to the nginx container on port 80, so that traffic coming through the load balancer flows into nginx. I want the traffic coming into nginx to be proxied to the fastapi container on port 8080.

BUT the task keeps getting stopped and goes into a failed state, and I encountered the following error in the nginx container.
`Task is stopping Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:~~)`
and this error `/usr/share/nginx/html/health" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.0.249, server: localhost, request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.10.216"` appeared in the nginx container log in cloudwatch.

Here is my nginx config code.

```
worker_processes  auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
http{
        upstream app {
                server fastapi:8080;                          
        }

        server {
                listen       80;
                listen       [::]:80;
                server_name  api.good.shop;
                        
                location / {
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

                        proxy_pass  http://app;             
                        proxy_redirect off;
                }
                location /health {
                        proxy_pass http://app/health;
                }
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
                access_log /var/log/access.log;
        }
}
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED

1. I attempted to access the nginx container to check the error logs and to verify if there was nothing in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory, but I was unable to access it due to the task getting stopped quickly.
2. I added `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` to the `/health` path in nginx to specify the root directory again.
3. There is a simple GET method API in the `/health` path of FastAPI. However, it seems like it cannot be found.
4. I thought it could be a problem with the security group, so I set it up to allow all IP addresses and traffic.

BUT the same error keeps appearing. How can I access and solve the problem? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: How are you resolving `http://app` to your application? Are you using some sort of ECS service mapping? Are these two containers running in the same ECS task?